# How would I go on changing the style when a different rarity is chosen. (Next.JS)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

How would I go on changing the style when a different rarity is chosen.
I'm making a game which chooses a random rarity for you when the website is loaded, and I want to set the color of the rarity.

This is how it looks like right now

[image]

```html
      <h1>Quality = {RandomQuality()}</h1>
      <h1>Rarity = {RandomRarity()}</h1>
```

Comment: you can use conditional style

Comment: @Soorajs, I've heard about conditonal styling, but never found a proper guide on how to use it. If you can help with that, that'll be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like that to add a CSS class

```jsx
<h1 class={`${rarity === 'Common' ? 'style-common' : 'style-normal'}`}>...</h1>
```

(if you need more options write a function for it)

or even use the "rarity" naming as CSS class if you need more variants

```jsx
<h1 class={`${rarity.toLowerCase()}`}>...</h1>
```

and in your CSS File

```css
.common {
/* your style for common here*/
}
.rare {
/* your style for rare here*/
}
```